# EventListener and audio events causing errors?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, html5-audio

I'm running into an annoying error, basically I'm using a third party editor to run a simple a game, I'm starting an audio file at the start of the scene, and after the audio ended I want to `goToNextScene()` which is a built in function. I am using Buzz JavaScript library. However I'm running into problem with this. If I attach the event listener directly to the sound var I get an "'undefined' is not a function" error.

```
var SceneSound = new buzz.sound(".../something.m4a");
SceneSound.play();
SceneSound.addEventListener('ended', checkEnding, false);
function checkEnding() {

    console.log("TEST");
    controller.goToNextScene();
}
```

and if I query the sound object first, I get a NULL error instead

```
var SceneSound = new buzz.sound(".../something.m4a");
SceneSound.play();
var objAudio = document.querySelector("#SceneSound audio");
SceneSound.addEventListener('ended', checkEnding, false);

function checkEnding() {

    console.log("TEST");
    controller.goToNextScene();
}
```

Sound plays and all, it's just attaching the `eventListener` is causing the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

U forgot to mention your Browser. Playing of audio is quite browser related.
Also don't use 3rd party libraries - use Audio TAG directly.

This is example:

```
function strNS(i){
switch (i){
    case 0 : return "EMPTY";
    case 1 : return "IDLE";
    case 2 : return "LOADING";
    case 3 : return "NO SOURCE";
} 
}

function strRS(i){
switch (i){
    case 0 : return "NOTHING";
    case 1 : return "METADATA";
    case 2 : return "CURRENT_DATA";
    case 3 : return "FUTURE_DATA";
    case 4 : return "ENOUGH_DATA";
} 
}

// Event Handler
function eh(e){

//console.log( "NS:" + strNS(e.currentTarget.networkState) + " RS:" +      strRS(e.currentTarget.readyState));

}

function ensureEvent(obj, prop){

if (obj.hasOwnProperty('on' + prop)){
    console.info(a + " does support '" + prop + "'")
    obj.addEventListener(prop, eh);

}else{
    console.log(a + " does not support '" + prop + "'");
}


}


var a = new Audio();

a.autoplay = true;
a.controls = true;

ensureEvent (a, 'loadstart');
ensureEvent (a, 'progress');
ensureEvent (a, 'suspend');
ensureEvent (a, 'load');
ensureEvent (a, 'abort');
ensureEvent (a, 'error');
ensureEvent (a, 'emptied');
ensureEvent (a, 'stalled');
ensureEvent (a, 'play');
ensureEvent (a, 'pause');
ensureEvent (a, 'loadedmetadata');
ensureEvent (a, 'loadeddata');
ensureEvent (a, 'waiting');
ensureEvent (a, 'playing');
ensureEvent (a, 'canplay');
ensureEvent (a, 'canplaythrough');
ensureEvent (a, 'seeking');
ensureEvent (a, 'timeupdate');
ensureEvent (a, 'ended');
ensureEvent (a, 'ratechange');
ensureEvent (a, 'durationchange');

a.src = "blablabla.mp3";
a.play();
```